# Excel Min Positive number with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get the location of **each** RefID based on the smallest positive number. The answer for the example below is:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFOmy.png)

```
RefID   Location    Number
vT70SAAS    Sixth Floor 311.39
wmhXXAAY    Sixth Floor 35.57
wm2xcAAA    Rooftop 7.55
```

I tried =MIN(IF(F27:F30>0,F27:F30)) as array, but it gets the overall min positive. I need one for each RefID

Sample data:

```
Number  Location    RefID
-3.50   Basement    wmhXXAAY
-32.39  First Floor wm2xcAAA
524.71  Second Floor    vT70SAAS
-7.19   Second Floor    wm2xcAAA
61.81   Third Floor wm2xcAAA
150.63  Third Floor wmhXXAAY
467.76  Fifth Floor wm2xcAAA
102.30  Fifth Floor wmhXXAAY
311.39  Sixth Floor vT70SAAS
35.57   Sixth Floor wmhXXAAY
521.51  Rooftop vT70SAAS
7.55    Rooftop wm2xcAAA
244.54  Rooftop wm2xcAAA
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNkw4.png)

Comment: query is a good option to solve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more option:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(($A$2:$A$14>0)*($C$2:$C$14=F2)))*$A$2:$A$14,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I used this approach since I just have to add a new column to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table is the best way. Especially if you are going to deal with larger datasets.

Make one from your data.  Add RefID as the ROW and Min(Number) as DATA

Then - If you want to add a value back to your original table (in another, adjacent column) - you could do a lookup on the pivot table.

=VLOOKUP(A1,F1:G5,2)

Where F1:G5 is the range of the pivot table.

If, for some reason, you need the VLOOKUP to work without being able to manually select the pivottable, then see this:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/use-pivot-table-name-in-a-formula/17aa5ad3-eee4-4a5c-a70c-a9296853066d

Answer (score 0):

Just add another condition to the `IF()`:

With data starting in the second row, array enter:

```
=MIN(IF((F2:F14>0)*(H2:H14="vT70SAAS"),F2:F14))
```

Note we use multiply rather than `AND()`

[image]

*(do the same for the other IDs)*

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using Power Query, available in Excel 2010+

Most steps can be done from the UI.

The Table renaming can be done manually, but I customized the code a bit in case you wind up adding extra columns.

#### Algorithm

- Filter the table for values > 0
- Group Rows by `RefID`, with `Operation = All Rows`
- Add a Custom Column with formula `Table.Min([Grouped],"Number")` to extract the RefID with the lowest Number
- Expand the Resultant column
- ReOrder the columns into the desired final order
- Remove the Extra columns
- Rename the resultant columns.

#### M-Code

*You may need to change the Table Name in Line 2*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="refIDtbl"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Number", type number}, {"Location", type text}, {"RefID", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Number] >= 0),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"RefID"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Number=number, Location=text, RefID=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Min([Grouped],"Number")),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Number", "Location", "RefID"}, {"Custom.Number", "Custom.Location", "Custom.RefID"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"RefID", "Grouped", "Custom.Location", "Custom.RefID", "Custom.Number"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Grouped", "Custom.RefID"}),

        oldColNames = Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns"),
        newColNames = List.ReplaceValue(oldColNames,"Custom.","",Replacer.ReplaceText),
        
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",List.Zip({oldColNames,newColNames}))
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

[image]